# How can I write data to Excel in rather long format without transforming data in Stata?

Tags: stata, spss

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
ID  Var1 Var2  
1   a1   b1  
2   a2   b2
3   a3   b3  
etc.
```

Now I want to write this data to an Excel file which will look like this:

```
ID=1
Var1 = a1 & Var2 = b1
ID=2
Var1 = a2 & Var2 = b2
ID=3
Var1 = a3 & Var3 = b3
etc.
```

It's like writing an Excel file that "loops" through values of these variables and puts them in Excel rows. One potential way I can think of is to create extra text variables and `reshape` data to long format. But is there a more efficient way to achieve this outcome and not have to do that? I did some search and it looks like `putexcel` may help, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: In SPSS, it can be done quite simply and directly, such as this syntax:

```
write outfile='DIRECTORY\output.xls'/"id = " tab id.  
write outfile='DIRECTORY\output.xls'/"Var1 =" tab Var1 tab "&" tab "Var2 =" tab Var2.
```

So I think there may be a similar way to do so in Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops over individual observations will be much slower than looping over variables.

Here are two potential ways of accomplishing your goal:

```
clear
input ID  str2 Var1 str2 Var2  
1   "a1"   "b1"  
2   "a2"   "b2"
3   "a3"   "b3" 
end

gen id = "ID=" + string(ID)
drop ID
gen cv = ""
foreach var of varlist Var1 Var2 {
    replace cv = cv + "`var'=" + `var' + " & "
    drop `var'
}
replace cv= regexr(cv," & $","") // remove trailing & 

/* Method 1: Stack & Sort */
preserve
sort id
stack id cv, into(column) clear
bys _stack: gen row=_n
sort row _stack
keep column
list, clean noobs
export excel using "myexcelfile_stack", replace
restore

/* Method 2: Reshape */
gen n=_n
rename (id cv) column#, addnumber
reshape long column, i(n) j(row)
keep column
list, clean noobs

export excel using "myexcelfile_reshape", replace
```

Comment: I tried the first method. Your program creates a data set with 2 variables _id_ and _cv_ and the exported Excel organizes these variables in _horizontal_ order. However, I need to organize them in _vertical_ order, as described in my original post. Reshaping will do the job, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way; that is, not to reshape data (the reshape program will be quite substantial with large number of variables).

Comment: @NonSleeper I should have been a tad clearer. Put the `export` part before the `restore`, or just get rid of `preserve`and `restore` lines entirely. I edited the post with the first suggestion.